# Sequential allocation problem using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I encountered the following allocation problem as follows.

Consider the following dataframe representing the supply schedule of some item.

```
supply_df = 
   item supplier  supply_week  supply
0     a       s1            1      10
1     a       s2            1      20
2     a       s3            1      10
3     a       s1            2      23
4     a       s2            2      33
5     a       s3            2      42
6     a       s1            3      52
7     a       s2            3      27
8     a       s3            3      29
9     b       s1            1      37
10    b       s2            1      32
11    b       s3            1      38
12    b       s1            2      17
13    b       s2            2      28
14    b       s3            2      44
15    b       s1            3      41
16    b       s2            3      45
17    b       s3            3      24
```

Here is the consumption information

```
consume_df =   
    item  week  consume
0    a     1       33
1    a     2      100
2    a     3      102
3    b     1       90
4    b     2      100
5    b     3       80
```

I wish to map which supply got consumed in which week and what quantity.

```
out_df = 
   item supplier  supply_week  supply  week  consume
0     a       s1            1      10     1       10
1     a       s2            1      20     1       20
2     a       s3            1      10     1        3
3     a       s3            1      10     2        7
4     a       s1            2      23     2       23
5     a       s2            2      33     2       33
6     a       s3            2      42     2       37
7     a       s3            2      42     3        5
8     a       s1            3      52     3       52
9     a       s2            3      27     3       27
10    a       s3            3      29     3       18
11    b       s1            1      37     1       37
12    b       s2            1      32     1       32
13    b       s3            1      38     1       21
14    b       s3            1      38     2       17
15    b       s1            2      17     2       17
16    b       s2            2      28     2       28
17    b       s3            2      44     2       38
18    b       s3            2      44     3        6
19    b       s1            3      41     3       41
20    b       s2            3      45     3       33
```

Notable points:

- It is already known that the consumption of supply shall happen in the order of preference of `s1` > `s2` > `s3` for the same week.
- Likewise, consumption will only happen on an earlier-week-earlier-consume basis.
- Supply of one item cannot contribute to another item.
- While consumption of an item in a given week can come from multiple suppliers, it is also possible for a supply from a given supplier to be split between multiple weeks.
- It is entirely possible for some supplier to have intermittent supply (not every week) unlike the sample problem above.
- Any leftover supply is not important.

I was able to do it using `pd.DataFrame.GroupBy.apply` or iterators like `pd.DataFrame.itertuples` and `pd.DataFrame.iterrows` with custom function applied, however, data being large in actual problem, it is not efficient.

Looking for a more efficient solution which can solve this problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an intermediate in which you compute the cumulated sums of supply and consumption, then compute the diff and handle the rows depending on the sign of this diff:

```
tmp = (supply_df
       .assign(supply_total=supply_df.groupby('item')['supply'].cumsum())
       .merge(consume_df.assign(total=consume_df.groupby('item')['consume'].cumsum()),
              left_on=['item', 'supply_week'], right_on=['item', 'week'])
       .assign(diff=lambda d: d['supply_total'].sub(d['total']))
       )

out = (pd.concat([tmp.assign(consume=tmp['supply'].sub(tmp['diff'].clip(lower=0)))
                     .query('consume>=0'),
                  tmp.query('diff>0')
                     .assign(week=lambda d: d.groupby('item')['week'].shift(-1),
                             consume=lambda d: d['diff']
                            )
                     .dropna(subset='week')
                 ])
         .sort_index(kind='stable')
         .drop(columns=['total', 'diff'])
      )
```

Output:

```
   item supplier  supply_week  supply  supply_total  week  consume
0     a       s1            1      10            10   1.0       10
1     a       s2            1      20            30   1.0       20
2     a       s3            1      10            40   1.0        3
2     a       s3            1      10            40   2.0        7
3     a       s1            2      23            63   2.0       23
4     a       s2            2      33            96   2.0       33
5     a       s3            2      42           138   2.0       37
5     a       s3            2      42           138   3.0        5
6     a       s1            3      52           190   3.0       52
7     a       s2            3      27           217   3.0       27
8     a       s3            3      29           246   3.0       18
9     b       s1            1      37            37   1.0       37
10    b       s2            1      32            69   1.0       32
11    b       s3            1      38           107   1.0       21
11    b       s3            1      38           107   2.0       17
12    b       s1            2      17           124   2.0       17
13    b       s2            2      28           152   2.0       28
14    b       s3            2      44           196   2.0       38
14    b       s3            2      44           196   3.0        6
15    b       s1            3      41           237   3.0       41
16    b       s2            3      45           282   3.0       33
16    b       s2            3      45           282   3.0       12
```

Comment: The solution looks somewhat good, but I was wondering if supply is such that, the cumulative consume takes multiple days to catchup, then `shift(-1)` may not give the correct consume week. Need to test through another mockup.

Comment: I changed the consume of `a` item for week 2 and 3 to be 10 and 10 respectively instead of 100 and 102. So, in principle with the given data, 'a', 's1', 2nd supply week is sufficient to satisfy all consume. However, I am getting some additional rows with supply week as 3 as well with some unrecognizable consume value which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
import pandas as pd

supply_data = {
    'item': ['a'] * 9 + ['b'] * 9,
    'supplier': ['s1', 's2', 's3'] * 6,
    'supply_week': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3] * 2, 
    'supply': [10, 20, 10, 23, 33, 42, 52, 27, 29, 37, 32, 38, 17, 28, 44, 41, 45, 24]
}

supply_df = pd.DataFrame(supply_data)

consume_data = {
    'item': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    'week': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    'consume': [33, 100, 102, 90, 100, 80]
}

consume_df = pd.DataFrame(consume_data)

merged_df = consume_df.merge(supply_df, left_on=['item', 'week'], right_on=['item', 'supply_week'])

# Sort the DataFrame by supplier and reset the index
merged_df.sort_values(by=['item', 'week', 'supplier'], inplace=True)
merged_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
merged_df.drop('supply_week', inplace=True, axis = 1)

results = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Item','Week','Supplier','Supply','Consumed'])

for _, group in merged_df.groupby(['item', 'week']):
    item = group['item'].iloc[0]
    week = group['week'].iloc[0]
    consume = group['consume'].iloc[0]
    remaining = consume
    for index, row in group.iterrows():
        supply = row['supply']
        remaining = remaining - supply
        if remaining > 0:
            results.loc[len(results.index)] = {'Item': item,'Week':week,'Supplier': row['supplier'],'Supply':supply,'Consumed':supply}
        elif remaining+supply < 0:
            results.loc[len(results.index)] = {'Item': item,'Week':week,'Supplier': row['supplier'],'Supply':supply,'Consumed':0}
        else:
            results.loc[len(results.index)] = {'Item': item,'Week':week,'Supplier': row['supplier'],'Supply':supply,'Consumed':remaining+supply}
```

Results from provided data:

| Item | Week | Supplier | Supply | Consumed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | s1 | 10 | 10 |
| a | 1 | s2 | 20 | 20 |
| a | 1 | s3 | 10 | 3 |
| a | 2 | s1 | 23 | 23 |
| a | 2 | s2 | 33 | 33 |
| a | 2 | s3 | 42 | 42 |
| a | 3 | s1 | 52 | 52 |
| a | 3 | s2 | 27 | 27 |
| a | 3 | s3 | 29 | 23 |
| b | 1 | s1 | 37 | 37 |
| b | 1 | s2 | 32 | 32 |
| b | 1 | s3 | 38 | 21 |
| b | 2 | s1 | 17 | 17 |
| b | 2 | s2 | 28 | 28 |
| b | 2 | s3 | 44 | 44 |
| b | 3 | s1 | 41 | 41 |
| b | 3 | s2 | 45 | 39 |
| b | 3 | s3 | 24 | 0 |

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I need an efficient solution and iterating over groups and rows is not efficient.

Comment: Fair enough. Will be keen to see how it's eventually handled!